# How to select an element from a list based on a function argument?

Tags: python-3.x

If I have a list of typles as the following:
List_of_tuples[(a, 100), (b,90), (c, 80), (d, 70), (e, 50)]

I want to write a function where I can pass a number as an argument n=2, for example, and it gets the 2 most frequent elements in the list above. If I pass n=3, this means it will get the 3 most frequent elements and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what the [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method of [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) does:

```
>>> list_of_tuples = [('a', 100), ('b', 90), ('c', 80), ('d', 70), ('e', 50)]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter(dict(list_of_tuples))
>>> counter.most_common(2)
[('a', 100), ('b', 90)]
```

The only non-obvious part about this code is that we need to construct the `Counter` by constructing a `dict` from the pairs first, otherwise `Counter` will actually count the tuples themselves.

Comment: list_of_tuples = [('a', 100), ('b', 90), ('c', 80), ('d', 70), ('e', 50)]
from collections import Counter

def select(n):
    counter = Counter(dict(list_of_tuples))
    return counter.most_common(n)

select(2)

Comment: I converted it into a function. your answer helped.